# ImageView .setScaleType() scales the bitmap, rather than setting the Drawable's bounds

Tags: android, svg, imageview

I am calling `.setImageDrawable()` on an `ImageButton` to provide its content from a `Drawable`. The actual `Drawable` being used is an `SVGDrawable` which comes from my own SVG library. The `SVGDrawable` properly overrides and supports methods such as `setBounds()` and so on.

I was hoping that, by using `.setScaleType()` on the `ImageView`, it would have the intelligence to tell the `Drawable` to adjust its bounds to match the parent `ImageView`. Unfortunately what seems to happen instead is that the `ImageView` tells the `Drawable` to draw at its intrinsic dimensions, and then the `ImageView` performs the scaling to the resultant bitmap, which looks bad.

Is there a means through the existing API that I've overlooked that could solve this?

Comment: if its your own Drawable ypu can always override getIntrinsicWidth/getIntrinsicHeight

Comment: Those methods are currently implemented, and they presently return the native SVG image size. I'm not sure how I would use or change those methods to solve this problem.

Comment: if you double the intrinsic size the ImageView will use that size and the effective scaling factor will be smaller which improve the look of your Drawable